# List not showing up on my localhost, but shows on jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to eventually make a sliding form with jQuery, but while testing out my html code I noticed the ul lists didn't show up on my apache localhost. Yet it shows up on the jsfiddle as one can see in the link--> http://jsfiddle.net/713Marketing/Awh3G/86/
Why is that? My jquery library is updated and `$(document).ready(function() {` is in the beg of my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the console.log to debug. First thing i would try is `console.log($('#navigation'));` and check your browser console to see if it returns the right object, and not 'undefined'.

If that works the next step would be to inspect the code of your `#navigation` block and see wich styles get applied after the code has ran. Perhaps you have something like `display: none !important;` in your stylesheet, wich would not get overwritten by the inline styles jQuery apllies to show the content. Or perhaps the block is positioned somewhere off-screen.

There is bound to be an isue somewhere else in your code, as the .show() function from jQuery is rather basic and has never caused me any problems.

If you can not find the issue, feel free to post a link to the live page so we can have a look at it and try to help out.

Comment: My display: none; was the problem. Thank you. One thing always leads to another, now the new problem is getting my pages to not all be on one page and transition

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the jQuery .show(), try the vanilla javascript. If nothing else, this may help diagnose your issue:

```
document.getElementById("navigation").setAttribute("style","");
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't work. I'm curious to know What is in jsfiddle that has the ul showing/working?

Comment: What browser are you testing your page in? Also, is there anything else going on in your server or browser that could be preventing scripts from running? did you make sure to include a reference to the javascript file or place that script inline on your html page? I would open a developer console and make sure that your script is loading.

Comment: Google chrome was the browser being tested. www.entrilab.com is the website I tried to implement it on. Still the same prob

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 $(function() {
      $("#navigation").show();
 });
```

or

```
function yolo(){
$("#navigation").show();      // make <body onload='yolo()>
}
```

I'm not exactly sure why your code isn't working.

Are you sure you included jQuery correctly?
And you made closing brackets and parentheses at the end of your function?:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#navigation").show();      //onload

 });
```